# Custom markup in mobiledoc-kit

Tags: ember.js, markup, node.js-addon, mobiledoc-kit

I'm using mobiledoc-kit to create an editor. It comes with a few toolbar buttons that let you make text bold, italic, etc. Some text can be wrapped in H1, H2... tags.

What I want is to create a button that will wrap text in a custom tag with attributes (`<div data-tag="some data here">TEXT</div>`)

I can see the tags are limited in `VALID_MARKUP_TAGNAMES` constant which is in src/js/models/markup.js file

I installed mobiledoc-kit via npm.

The question is how can I extend this file and add a custom tag to the constant.

Comment: Would be of interest for me too